# Directly read JPEG YUV data

Tags: python, jpeg

Is there any way to extract an array of Y and UV channels directly?

I could only find PIL and OpenCV examples that do unnecessary colorspace conversions YUV -> RGB -> YUV, which is destructive.

Comment: Why do you think that YUV to RGB and back to YUV is destructive?  Most YUV formats have less Y bytes than UV bytes.  So if anything, the conversion from YUV to RGB back to YUV is akin to taking an 8-bit image, saving it as 24-bit, then saving it back to 8-bit.

Comment: @selbie As a simple example, `yuv {128, 0, 255}` is equal to `rgb {419, -20, 128}`, but those values get clipped to within `[0, 255]` so we're left with `rgb {255, 0, 128}`.

Comment: Right.  But what does `rgb(255,0,128)` map back to in YUV space?

Comment: Please provide the example(s) you say you found to indicate what you're looking to do exactly and where you think the problem lies.

Comment: @selbie `rgb {255, 0, 128}` becomes `yuv {90, 18, 144}`. (Using [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV#SDTV_with_BT.601) matrix for reference, though any would produce similar results.)

Comment: I stand corrected.  It's not a stable conversion between RGB to YUV.

Comment: @selbie Besides out-of-range values, I would expect any conversion to degrade accuracy slightly, simply because of rounding errors.